# Bounds and uniqueness of a transcendental equation

Tags: calculus, polynomials, transcendental-equations

Let $p\in[0,1]$ and $\rho(x): [0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$  such that

$$\int_0^1 dx \rho(x) = 1.$$ I'd like to investigate the following transcendental equation:

$$\frac{1}{2p} = \int_0^{1} dx x^{\gamma -1} \rho(x)$$

In particular I wish to find bounds for $\gamma$ and say something about the uniqueness of the solution. I tried to re-formulate the problem by employing the first mean value theorem for integration, i.e.

$$\int_0^{1} dx x^{\gamma -1} \rho(x)= \xi^{\gamma-1} \int_0^{1} dx \rho(x)=\xi^{\gamma - 1}$$

with $\xi\in [0,1]$.  That is I'd like to know something about the uniqueness and possible bounds for $\gamma$ in

$$\frac{1}{2p} = \xi^{\gamma - 1}$$

Is this a achievable target? Any ideas? I suppose when restricting $\gamma$ to the real numbers one has

$$\gamma = 1- \frac{\log{(2p)}}{\log{(\xi)}}$$

But what about the uniqueness of $\xi$ in the first mean value theorem for integration or $\gamma$ can also be complex...

Answer (score 1):

Fix $p$ and $\rho(x)$. By uniqueness, I think you are asking if you can have two distinct values $a,b$ such that $\int_0^1 x^a\rho(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^b\rho(x)dx = 1/(2p)$.

Restricting to the reals:  If a function $f(x)$ is non-negative and satisfies $\int_0^1f(x)dx = 0$, then $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.  So, for example, suppose $0\leq a <  b$.  Then $(x^a - x^b)\rho(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  Thus, if $\int_0^1(x^a-x^b)\rho(x)dx = 0$, we know $(x^a-x^b)\rho(x)=0$ almost everywhere.  But $x^a=x^b$ only for $x=0$ or $x=1$.  Thus $\rho(x)=0$ almost everywhere, which contradicts $\int_0^1\rho(x)dx=1$.

---

In the complex case:  If $z$ is a complex number with a nonzero imaginary part, and if $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x)dx = 1/(2p)$, then this equality also holds for the complex conjugate $\overline{z}$, and so the answer is *not* unique.  But that requires finding out if there is such a $z$.  This can depend on $\rho(x)$.

Example 1: Suppose $\rho(x)=1$ for $x \in [0,1]$.  Then for any real number $c\neq 0$, the equation $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x) dx = c$ has one and only one solution $z$, and that solution is real. Specifically, $z=1/c - 1$.

Example 2:  Suppose $\rho(x) = 2$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$, $\rho(x)=0$ else.  Then $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x) dx = \frac{(1/2)^{z}}{z+1}$ can be the same real number for multiple complex solutions $z$.   For example, if $z=a+ib$ then $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x) dx$ is real whenever $a = -b\cot(b\log(2))-1$.  If $b=5$ then $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x)dx$ is real and satisfies $\int_0^1 x^z\rho(x)dx = \int_0^1x^{\overline{z}}\rho(x)dx > 3844$.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed that was what I meant by uniqueness. So when I can show that any solution $\gamma$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ then the uniqueness part is answered. Now when $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ write $\gamma -1= a+ib$. This implies $1/2p = \xi^{a+ib} = \xi^{a} e^{ib\ln \xi}$ and I think it follows $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ ($b=0$), because $1/2p \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @antarcticfox: Well, you could have $e^{i b \ln \psi}$ is real even if $b \neq 0$. I don't know how to make or pronounce that symbol you made. =)

Comment: Ah yes, you are right :-( . For the letter see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi_%28letter%29

Comment: I looked on the wikipedia link.  Got it:  $\xi$. =)

Comment: Also, I don't think the mean value theorem for integration always holds for the complex number case.

Comment: That is another problem...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think you are right in what you said about the complex case. It is hardly possible to say something in general.